# "Easy" exercise about Cauchy's problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Happy new year!

I have some doubts trying to solve next exercise about differential equations:

Consider $$\begin{cases}
          x'=f(t,x), \\
          x(t_0)=x_0,\\
     \end{cases}$$
where $$f:\mathbb{R^2}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$$
is defined by
$$
f(t,x) =\left\{
        \begin{array}{}
            0  & \quad x \leq 0 \thinspace\text{or}\thinspace t\leq0, \\
            -2x/t & \quad 0<x\leq t^2, \\
            -2t & \quad x \geq t^2 > 0.
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
This function is continuous in all plane $\mathbb{R^2}$ and is locally Lipschitz in compacts because partial derivates are bounded. So, Picard's Theorem says that there are an unique solution for all $(t_0, x_0)\in\mathbb{R^2}$.

My problem is trying to find them. Which are the solutions for every $(t_0, x_0)$? In particular, for $(0,0)$? My idea: if $x_0<t_0^2$ then I can easily solve  the differential equation $x'=2x/t$. But is this correct? What happens if $x_0=t_0^2$ or $x_0$ goes to $t_0^2$? And if $x_0=t_0=0$, then the solution is always $0$?

First time I looked this exercise I thought it was easy, but I having some doubts. Any help? Thank you.

Comment: $\partial f/\partial x$ is not bounded.

Comment: @AnneBauval lol still awake? Thanks for your help b4, I got it now.

Comment: As Anne Bauval pointed out, $f$ is not Lipschitz because $\partial_xf$ is not bounded, but it is still continuous, so Peano's theorem guarantees the existence of a solution, perhaps not unique nevertheless. If the second line in the definition $f$ were $+2x/t$, $x(t) = -t^2$ would have been an easy guess, but as such, I haven't found any solution notwithstanding.

Comment: $f$ is ill-defined because the cases overlap: if $t<0$ then $t^2>0.$